# Where is the require('styles') in React Native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to work through the react native examples. One thing i cannot understand is why there is no explicit require('styles') to pull in my styles from styles.js.

Answer (score 0):

You can require your styles like this:

```
var styles = require('./stylesheet');
```

As long as they are exported like this:

stylesheet (stylesheet.js)

```
var myStyles = StyleSheet.create({
  bold: {
    fontWeight: 'bold'
  }
});

module.exports = myStyles;
```

Then use it like so:

```
<Text style={styles.bold}>
```

Comment: Updated styles declaration. Misnamed variable but it should work now, sorry!